# Ошибка с юникодом при компиляции pypy

Tags: python, utf-8, pypy

При компиляции через PyPy программа падает после строчки (так как потом полученные данные не могут обработаться):

```py
files_frac=os.listdir(FRAC_DIR)
```

В папке `FRAC_DIR` лежат файлы с названиями с кириллицей. При интерпретации через интерпретатор Python проблем нет, а вот PyPy выдает следующую ошибку:

```
string = string.encode(encoding, errors)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\xd4' in position 18: surrogates not allowed
```

Менять название файлов, к сожалению, очень сильно не желательно. Не могу понять, как решить проблему.

UPD: Вот как читае одинаковую папку PyPy (слева) и Python (справа). Файл с названием на кириллице (последний) читает по-разному:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось обойти проблему с помощью функции `os.scandir()` ([PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)).

Она возвращает класс `DirEntry`, у которого есть поля `name` и `path` - имя элементов в папке (файла или папки) и полный путь до элемента соответственно. Причем тут уже никаких проблем с кириллицей нет, к тому же функция работает быстрее.